# Recognizing failures word?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm searching for a word that describes the emotion or sense that you have when you have recognized your own failures. A characteristic that describes this emotion.

Example:

> I have ___ because I know what it's like to fail. Last year, I failed my first three tests.

Comment: What sort of recognition? Are you saying that you have empathy with another person because you also have failed? Or you've accepted that failure is a part of life? or... what? What exactly are you trying to convey with this word?

Comment: I have *resignation*, or better, I have *resigned myself*.

Answer (score 1):

[Humility](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/humility)

> the quality or state of not thinking you are better than other people; the quality or state of being humble

Comment: I was trying to put my finger on this word. *Humility* is one of the emotions or senses I would feel.

Answer (score 0):

Your example indicates you are looking for a noun. Consider ***regret*** and synonyms remorse,  repentance, penitence, disappointment & dejection.

ODO:

> **[regret](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/regret)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** [mass noun] A feeling of sadness, repentance, or disappointment over an occurrence or something that one has done or failed to do:
>   ‘he had to decline, to his regret’
>
> ‘It's hoped that it will reduce feelings of regret, remorse and guilt,
>   which are all core to the experience of Post Traumatic Stress.’
>
> ‘Later, he expressed his regret over the incident, but Tyra had
>   already come to a decision.’

Answer (score 0):

**[Chagrin](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chagrin)**

> disquietude or distress of mind caused by humiliation, disappointment, or failure

[MW]

I think this is the work you're looking for, although usage in your example is slightly awkward, mostly because chargrin, to my ear, always sounds like it's awkward to use. An example from the same reference is

> The fact that he'd been unable to attend the funeral was a source of chagrin for Ted.

Your example could be made into

> Last year, I failed my first three tests much to my chagrin.

or

> To my chagrin, I failed my first three tests.